# How to use v-virtual-scroll with v-table?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have a Vuetify table dealing with large amounts of data ( e.g. 300 rows with 20 columns ) and many rows come with calculated rowspans.

I want to speed up performance by using the `v-virtual-scroll` component but [this sample code](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) ( without using any rowspans )

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <v-virtual-scroll :height="500" :items="contents">
            <template v-slot:default="{ item }">
              <tr>
                  <td>{{ item }}</td>
                  <td>{{ item }}</td>
              </tr>
            </template>
          </v-virtual-scroll>
        </tbody>
      </v-table>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

const contents = ref(Array(1000).fill("cell"))
</script>
```

shows that the output is not the desired one

[image]

I would expect 1000 table rows with 2 columns side by side. I think this won't work because the scroll component is wrapping additional DOM elements around the table rows.

Does someone know how to achieve the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

If one uses the [`renderless` property](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-virtual-scroll/#props-renderless) that was added to the component in later versions of the vuetify, then this problem is solved.

(i.e. Change `<v-virtual-scroll :height="500" :items="contents">` to `<v-virtual-scroll :height="500" :items="contents" renderless>` and update the version of vuetify used, [then this works](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)